# When i add where in query it's now showing count 0

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm having a problem with a query is not showing `COUNT` 0 when i'm adding where clause.

I have two tables "Parking" & "Active_Parking".  I want to get `COUNT` of active parkings per `id_parking` that `datetime_out` is `>=` then current time to compare with `parking_space`.

```
Parking
| id_parking     | parking_name | parking_location | parking_space |
| -------------- | ------------ | ---------------- |  ------------ |
| 1              | ABC          |  1st street      | 35            |
| 1              | ABC          |  2nd street      | 50            |
| 1              | ABC          |  3rd street      | 150           |

Active Parking
| id_active_parking   |  id_parking | car_plates | datetime_IN          | 
| ------------------- | ----------- | ---------- | -------------------- |
| 1                   | 1           | 00-XXX-00  | 2018-12-16 14:00:00  |
| 2                   | 1           | 00-XXX-00  | 2018-12-16 14:21:34  |
| 3                   | 2           | 00-XXX-00  | 2018-12-16 21:35:00  |
| 4                   | 2           | 00-XXX-00  | 2018-12-16 22:00:00  |

| datetime_OUT         |
| -------------------- |
| 2018-12-16 15:00:00  |
| 2018-12-16 15:21:34  |
| 2018-12-16 22:35:00  |
| 2018-12-16 23:00:00  |
```

Query:

```
SELECT
  p.id_parking, 
  p.parking_name,
  p.parking_location,
  p.parking_space, 
  COUNT(ap.id_parking) AS Active
FROM
  parking p
  LEFT JOIN active_parking ap 
    ON ap.id_parking = p.id_parking
WHERE
  ap.datetime_OUT >= '2018-12-16 22:16:00'
GROUP BY p.id_parking
```

Query Result:

```
| id_parking     | COUNT(ap.id_parking) |
| -------------- | -------------------- |
| 2              | 2                    |
```

Is not showing  `id_parking` 1 and 3 `COUNT = 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the reason to use LEFT JOIN in this case? Remove group by + count and check the result. I believe you should use INNER JOIN in this case. You can read about differences in many places, including [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29)

If you really need all list of p.id_parking, you should move your WHERE clause to ON:

```
LEFT JOIN active_parking ap ON (
        ap.id_parking = p.id_parking
    AND ap.datetime_OUT >= '2018-12-16 22:16:00'
)
```

Then you should have proper count of active parkings.

Comment: thanks for answered. I'm using LEFT JOIN because with INNER JOIN is not showing other's id's